# Should I use getX() to get a variable X even if I am 'inside' the class?

Tags: oop, object, language-agnostic

I'd like to know whether, when I am coding a class, I should use getters and setters to access other instance variables (or just call them by their names). I think this creates unecessary noise, but I'd like to hear what you guys have to say about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code internal to the class can always access the private members without using the set and get methods for clarity that it is it's own members in use. Just my 2 cents.

Also you can consider: http://codenaut.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-avoid-getter-and-setter-methods.html

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful to use the getter / setter if they actually do something like validation and to access this variable you need to do these things every time. The first example that comes to my mind is if you do multithreading and before you set the new value you want to be sure that no one else acces the variable at the same time.... Otherwise, if the getter/setter do nothing but get and set the variable, I don't see any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Getters/setters main purpose is separate users of your class from changes of your class implementation. You're inside your class implementation. Despite this I would still recommend to use getters/setters until you're clearly need to access variables directly.